# Help regading not in and inner join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. Table1 and Table2

**Table1**

```
id tid
1  100
2  200
3  300
```

**Table2**

```
tid name
100 A
200 B
```

I want to take out id of records from Table1 whichever's tid is not present in Table2.

My output should be like this.

**Table1.id**

```
3
```

For this i have written following queries but it is taking too much of time. Since 
both tables have more amount of records.

please help me how to write a query for this such a way that it will take less amount of time.

```
select id from Table1 where tid not in (select tid from Table2)
select a.id from Table1 a inner join Table2 b on a.tid<>b.tid
```

TIA.

Comment: Your second query will nearly compute a cartesian product and only remove a small number of lines. This is definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a left join, and then use the WHERE clause to filter only to rows where the join didn't work:

```
SELECT
     a.ID
from
     Table1 a
         left join
     Table2 b
         on
            a.tid = b.tid
where
    b.tid is null
```

Of course, this still might not work fast enough, in which case you need to check whether you have indexes on the tid columns in these two tables.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
select id
from table1
where tid IN (
  select tid from table1
  minus
  select tid from table2 
)
```

set operations (minus part above) are pretty fast in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

First create indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX t1_tid ON table1 (tid ASC);
CREATE INDEX t2_tid ON table2 (tid ASC);
```

This way it could be faster.

Regarding the query, what about:

```
SELECT tid FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT tid FROM table2
```

Comment: id from table1 and tid from table2 aren't in the same domain (you'd want tid from table1 in the minus, but the OP wants the id values)

Answer (score 1):

You can try "not exists" too:

```
select * 
from Table1 T1 
where not exists (select 1 
                  from Table2 T2 
                  where T1.tid=t2.tid
                 );
```